# Impossible to simulate in XCode 4.5

Tags: ios, simulator, xcode4.5

Since update to XCode 4.5 I am unable to open my apps in the simulator.

It says "Finished Running  on iPhone 5.0 Simulator".

Sometimes, after retrying twice or thrice, the Simulator finally launches but the App never starts in it.

I am getting mad with this new version of XCode.

I have started a brand new project with a simple "Hello World" view. Even a clean brand new project cannot solve the problem.

Am I really missing something hidden in the config ?

Thanks

Lionel

**Edit 9/21**

When I try to run on my iPad 2 with iOS 5.1, I have the following error that may be linked to what I described above :

"Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device."

- My Project deployment target is 5.0
- My Project build settings : Valid architectures = armv7 armv7s
- My Target deployment target is 5.0
- My Target base SDK is 6.0
- My Target valid architectures are : armv7 armv7s

On my iPhone 4 updated to iOS 6 : same error.

Comment: Have u downloaded the iOS5 Simulator? You can check this under preferences -> Downloads -> Components

Comment: I have the following components also installed :
 - Command line tools
 - iOS 4.3 Simulator
 - iOS 5.0 Simulator
 - iOS 5.1 Simulator

Comment: Check your scheme. Click on the name of your app in the project toolbar, then Edit Scheme...Click on Run _App_ on the left hand side and the _info_ tab.   Make sure that Launch Automatically is selected.

Comment: I also have problems when launching on a Device. I have edited my post about this.

Answer (score 1):

Again, I started from scratch, deleting all information from the app and putting back each file carefully, and everything works seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unlikely it's any of your settings. Xcode just gets into a weird state like that sometimes. Usual fixes are force quit Xcode, force quit simulator, reboot.